# Saiku OLAP wizard - "OK" button not working in Pentaho 5.2 Community Edition(CDE)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, saiku

I'm using Pentaho 5.2 Community Edition i can open the SAIKU OLAP Wizard and create an Analysis. But when clicking the "ok" button nothing happens. Anyone have solution for this issue?

Comment: many bugs are their in 5.2 so may be this is one of it.. but not sure..

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Saiku 3.0.8 so install "Saiku 2.6(depreciated)" it resolves your problem...hope it will help out...

Answer (score 0):

As everyone keep saying, it's probably a pentaho bug. I would recommend you to avoid using Saiku Olap Wizard in CDE. Instead, you can use OLAP Chart Wizard or MDX Query (copying & pasting the query that Saiku Standalone gives you).